# Запуск скрипта после установки windows 10

Tags: powershell

Необходимо запустить батник сразу после установки системы win10, который будет производить установку программы. Сам установочник и скрипт будут уже лежать в дистрибутиве. Данную программу не возможно установить через режим аудита(sysprep), т.к. она привязывается к железу машины. Либо же запускать его во время установки системы.